# Multi-table query in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have four Access tables.

```
Invoices (Date, JobNumber)
PO1 (Cost, JobNumber)
PO2 (Cost, JobNumber)
PO3 (Cost, JobNumber)
```

All have a joining column called JobNumber.
I already do a query on Invoices between two dates to create a table of JobNumbers.

```
SELECT JobNumber FROM Invoices WHERE (Date > "startDate") AND (Date < "endDate") INTO tempTable;
```

I am more used to SQL Server and mySQL with PHP where the next steps would be trivial using temp tables and multiple lines of SQL. But the Access Query designer doesn't allow such things. So I am not sure how to design a query across 4 tables in Access. I now want to do for PO1 to PO3:

```
SELECT SUM(PO1.Price) AS TotalPrice FROM P01,tempTable WHERE PO1.JobNumber=tempTable.JobNumber;
```

Then return the sum of all the costs for that JobNumber.
Any pointers welcome.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the Access query designer not supporting multiple tables - look for the 'Show Table' command on the toolbar/ribbon or context menu. That said, if you're happy writing the SQL directly, why not just do that? (Look for 'SQL View' in the UI, e.g. via the context menu again.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL has built in ways to do joins, in a case like this you don't need to resort to using temporary tables. The following query should produce the grand total over PO1, PO2 and PO3, if you go into design query and then select the SQL view.

```
Select
    i.JobNumber,
    Sum(c.Cost) as TotalCost
From
    Invoices as i
        Left Outer Join (
            Select
                Cost,
                JobNumber
            From
                PO1
            Union All
            Select
                Cost,
                JobNumber
            From
                PO2
            Union All
            Select
                Cost,
                JobNumber
            From
                PO3
        ) as c
        On i.JobNumber = c.jobNumber
Where
    i.Date >= #StartDate# And
    i.Date < #EndDate#
Group By
    i.JobNumber
```

There are a lot of moving parts in here. The first thing you could do to understand it is to create a separate query for the internal select. So, create a query called AllPO, with the following definition:

```
Select
    Cost,
    JobNumber
From
    PO1
Union All
Select
    Cost,
    JobNumber
From
    PO2
Union All
Select
    Cost,
    JobNumber
From
    PO3
```

Then you can redefine the first query as

```
Select
    i.JobNumber,
    Sum(c.Cost) as TotalCost
From
    Invoices as i
        Left Outer Join
    AllPO as c
        On i.JobNumber = c.jobNumber
Where
    i.Date >= #StartDate# And
    i.Date < #EndDate#
Group By
    i.JobNumber
```

This is kind of like using a temporary table, except the query optimizer is free to use more efficient techniques if it can find one.

Comment: Thanks a million Laurence that is spot on. I am not used to having to do everything in one line of SQL.