# MS-Access: Too many tables and way too big of a file - Multiple linked-tables query?

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access

So just FYI, I have very limited SQL training, and my new position is requiring that I learn so please be gentle with me :)

First off, I saw this:

[Multi-table query in Microsoft Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333738/multi-table-query-in-microsoft-access/19334110#19334110)

And that is exactly what I need in principle; however, my data structure is a little different. I have roughly 24 databases each averaging around 1gb of  information over 8 years across 420 institutions (4 databases for each year - about 16 million observations in total). Every field is identical across databases.

I need to run analyses on all of this information, but ms-access databases are limited to 2gb, so I'm trying to figure out a workaround. My idea is to link each table into a master database, and then run queries using the selection query from the above link. My question is whether or not this will actually work. My computer has 32gb of physical memory, so I feel like I should be able to load all of it into active memory while performing any queries, but I still don't know. Is there a more efficient way?

Basically, what I need to be able to query institutions over years. Right now that's impossible and it's causing issues. Because institutions aren't subjected to any scrutiny regarding the information they report, we need to understand how reporting trends evolved within and between them over time.

I was given a list of about 40 questions that all involve different queries that we need to run, so I'm hoping against hope that I can figure out a solution that doesn't involve me losing my mind.

Thank you all for your help!

-David

Comment: Do yourself a favor and import all the data into one database on a real RDBMS (SQLServer, Oracle, MySQL, etc).

Comment: I don't have any other software installed on my computer and I can't install any others (work rules). Plus jumping into a pure programming environment without the nice GUI of access is daunting. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Ouch! Need more information: (1) How many tables in each database do you need to search - 1, 2, 3..? (2) How many fields in each table, and how many fields will you need to query/report? Running a couple of queries is manageable, but 40 would require a little more complexity.  For just one query, I think you could 'summarize' each existing database, which hopefully would be small enough to be dealt with, then possibly combine the results into one table. You could use some VBA code to repeat your process across all databases.

Comment: You can link as many tables from as many databases as you need to a front end.  First thing I would do is to compact & repair each database to optimise its allocated space. If this has never been done, it can dramatically reduce the databases.  
If each database contains a single table that has the same fields in each database, you can use `UNION ALL` to create a query that will bind all tables together. Save that query as `MasterQuery` and then run your other queries and reports against that one table. It's not going to be efficient and it will probably be very slow, but it should work.

Comment: Alternatively, give us a bit more information about your project and we may be able to give you more tips to make the process more efficient.  
Other solutions would involve pre-processing the data you need using VBA and some ad-hoc queries in order to reduce it for further processing.  You could also run each query on each table and collate the results using VBA.  
Basically, table linking is your friend. There are ways to do that automatically from VBA as well to help you automate the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, I apologize for the slow response (thanksgiving and all!) I have 1 table per database with 65 fields which are constant across all tables and databases. Because of this, the `UNION ALL` command was going to be my go-to. A preliminary step that is going to take a good amount of time is getting a summary of each field by institution. Each field typically has a finite number of possible entries, so I want to know what entries each institution uses (most leave them blank, so knowing which use them are the first step towards analyzing the fields).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly acceptable to link all the tables into one master database.  In my previous experience I had one master database with over 80 backends, many with one large table.  The issue with querying them is that a single Access query can also only be 2Gb.  So if it any time in the processing your query exceeds that limit you'll get an error.  It can be very annoying.  For me the best way to work around this is temp tables and driver/parameter tables.  Use driver/parameter table to store what data you'll be pulling from a source.  This creates more efficient queries.  Especially if you index on the join fields.  In my master database I always had a form with VB code to load the driver/parameter tables.

Now all that said you'll be much happier in a different environment, even SQL Server Express.  Then you'll be able to use the 32Gb of memory.  Otherwise you'll always be dealing with not only the Access 2Gb file/query limit but also that Access is a 32-bit application and it can't address all the memory you have.